# Unused args in watcher function

Tags: concurrency, clojure

Here is a code example from [Clojure Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449394701)

```
(def history (atom ()))
(defn log->list
  [dest-atom key source old new]
  (when (not= old new)
    (swap! dest-atom conj new)))
(def sarah (atom {:name "Sarah" :age 25}))
(add-watch sarah :record (partial log->list history))
(swap! sarah update-in [:age] inc)
(swap! sarah identity)
(pprint @history)
```

The `log->list` function has two args `key` and `source` that never gets used. What are they for here?

Answer (score 0):

the key is the tag used to later remove it:

```
(remove-watch reference key)
```

If the key is then passed to the watching function then it has the ability to later remove it's self once it has been triggered. Though you can build that by agreeing on the key name in advance as well, though having this feature can make things more elegant.

Comment: This is perplexing, why does the key has to appear in the function itself?

Comment: it would be polite to use `_` instead

Answer (score 0):

From the docstring on add-watch:

> Adds a watch function to an agent/atom/var/ref reference. The watch
>   fn must be a fn of 4 args: a key, the reference, its old-state, its
>   new-state...

Because we're adding a watch on the atom, `log->list` needs to be a 4 arity function. We will get passed the key, reference, old value, and new value. Even though we only use the old and new values, we need to have 4 args in the function so it has the right arity.

It is often idiomatic in Clojure to use an underscore in place of an unused argument in a function definition to show it is unused, and to reduce visual noise. However in this case, I think keeping the unused variables and naming them makes it clearer what's happening and makes it easier to modify this in the future if necessary. This is particularly important as we need to keep the arity of this function exactly the same for it to work with add-watch. In a book, I would lean towards this option.

In actual code it's borderline and I could go either way on underscore vs naming the args. What I chose would probably depend on the context and whatever struck the right balance of clarity and conciseness.